# Fixed width floated div with flexible width content

Tags: css, css-float

I have content in a fixed-width container that I am trying to format like so:

```
Description: [button][button]
```

Basically, the description label takes up 50%, the button controls take up 50%. I am doing this by floating the description like so:

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <div style="width: 145px; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">Description:</div>
  <div>[button][button]</div>
</div>
```

In the case that there are more buttons than will fit on the right side, rather than having them wrap like this:

```
Description: [button][button]
[button][button]
```

I'd rather have the layout look like:

```
Description: 
[button][button][button][button]
```

So basically, I am having trouble coming up with a simple layout that will keep the description label at 50% width, keep the controls unwrapped and handle both cases above. I am positive I am missing something simple - any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my demo [on JsBIN](http://jsbin.com/okesuz/2/edit)

Use the `white-space` property to prevent from line-breaking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `white-space` and `float` as seen here on this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UGEBM/1/